# Setting custom Request Headers through nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I have a kubernetes cluster using nginx controller to proxy requests to the backend. There is an LB in the front.

LB <-> Nginx Ingress <-> WLS in K8s

When I terminate the SSL at the LB, and the backend sends a redirect it will send the redirect with location that starts with http. However, WebLogic recognizes WL-PROXY-SSL request header to send a https redirect.

I am trying to set the request header on the Nginx Ingress controller for a specific URL patterns only.

Tried using

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header WL-PROXY-SSL: "true";
```

It didn't work.

Even tried ....

```
more_set_headers "WL-PROXY-SSL: true";
    nginx.org/location-snippets: |
      proxy_set_header "WL-PROXY-SSL: true";
```

Also tried the custom-headers module but it sets for all resources. While I see the entry in the nginx.conf, it is not taking effect even with global custom-headers configMap also.

Is there any good example of adding this header to the request ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By saying `Also tried the custom-headers module but it sets for all resources.` did you mean [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/customization/custom-headers)?

Comment: Please ignore this question. My ingress configuration was incorrect which was the root cause.

Comment: Yes. I meant the same config you mentioned in the link

Comment: Consider posting an answer explaining the actual problem and steps taken in order to fix it.